# DevTools window for Chrome extension background script closes while debugging it

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm [debugging a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029) that uses [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) to set up some periodic notifications.

The problem is that why debugging the background page, Chrome closes its DevTools window out of the blue. at `chrome://extensions`, I have have to click `Inspect views: background page (inactive)` again.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) docs:

> Event Pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.

To temporarily disable that behavior for debugging purposes, set `persistent: true` in `manifest.json` and reload the extension.